# Torquebox will not load with Oracle

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, oracle, jruby, torquebox

I have a Rails 3.2.13 application written in JRuby (1.7.12). I'm developing on Mac OS X 10.10 (though the problem was also evident on 10.9). I have both JDK 1.6 and 1.7 installed. I'm serving the application via torquebox 3.1.1.

If I start the application connecting to my local postgres database, I have no issues. But I need to debug a problem that requires connecting to Oracle. I then switch my adapter to `oracle-enhanced` and making sure I have ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc7.jar in `$JRUBY_HOME/lib`. When I start the application via torquebox, I get errors like this:

```
14:47:58,242 ERROR [org.torquebox.core.runtime] (pool-8-thread-1) Error during execution: ENV['RAILS_ROOT']=RACK_ROOT
ENV['RAILS_ENV']=RACK_ENV
require %q(org/torquebox/web/rails/boot)
: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `blame_file!' forjava.lang.StackOverflowError:Java::JavaLang::StackOverflowError
```

I realize the `blame_file!` error is a separate thing. The StackOverflowError that's the cause of that error is what I care about. It's getting into a failing loop when trying to load necessary files, like `rails/boot` in this case.

*However!* When I run "rails console" it works fine and I can load data from the database.

I'm convinced as a result of being able to load the console that this is a problem with torquebox somehow, but I don't know what, nor how to fix it.

Is there any helps anyone can give me? Has anyone seen something like this before? Thanks.

(Edit, I found a locally cached copy of ojdbc7.jar in the app, which explains my original errors with 1.6. I've edited this post to reflect the current situation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/976 to work around the blame_file problem and then hopefully you'll get a more useful error message.
Maybe then you'll get something be able to diagnose something similar to:
[Error while loading java Class in Jruby application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468973/error-while-loading-java-class-in-jruby-application)

Comment: But when I do this, I get the same errors that were wrapped. You can see above, the error is actually because it can't load `org/torquebox/web/rails/boot`. And after I change activesupport to handle `blame_file!`, I still see that.

`08:39:25,807 ERROR [org.torquebox.core.runtime] (pool-8-thread-1) Failed to initialize runtime: : org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) load error: org/torquebox/web/rails/boot -- java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on irc.freenode.net/#torquebox. After some confusion about the stack output vs. my stack size, it was suggested that I scale that back some. I set it from 4096m (yes, I realize now that that's ridiculous) to 2048k, and it works.

We don't know why Java crapped out in this specific way, but the end result is that with a smaller stack size, it works now.